# scipy.stats.ttest_ind returning a p-value of 0.0

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, p-value, hypothesis-test

I am trying to conduct a hypothesis test, but I am getting a p-value of 0.0. I can understand if it is really small, but a 0.0 is leading me to believe that there is an error. Here is my code:

```
results = st.ttest_ind(
    ultimate_users['monthly_profit'], 
    surf_users['monthly_profit'], 
    nan_policy = 'omit')

print('p-value: ', results.pvalue)
```

output:

```
p-value:  0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't necessarily an error. If the p-value is smaller than the smallest (normal) double precision floating point number (~`1e-308`), it [underflows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_underflow) and you get a zero. This would not be a bug in your code or in SciPy; it's just a fundamental limitation of floating point arithmetic.

If your sample size is large, it doesn't take much of a difference in sample means to get a zero p-value.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
rng = np.random.default_rng(83469358365936)
x = rng.random(1000)
stats.ttest_ind(x, x + 1)
# TtestResult(statistic=-76.66392731424226, pvalue=0.0, df=1998.0)
```

If you really want to know the true p-value, use [arbitrary precision arithmetic](https://mpmath.org/doc/current/functions/gamma.html#betainc) and the definition of the [t distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution) CDF.

```py
from mpmath import mp
t = mp.mpf(res.statistic)
nu = mp.mpf(res.df)
x2 = nu / (t**2 + nu)
p = mp.betainc(nu/2, mp.one/2, x2=x2, regularized=True)
print(p)
# 1.72157326887951e-597
```